# Having an issue loading a TFLite model into Flutter (issue with file-path)

Tags: tensorflow, flutter

I'm trying to load a TFLite model / it's labels into flutter but I keep getting a file not found error. Is it possibly a mistake in my code for loading the model:

**Code:**

```
loadModel() async{
    String res = await Tflite.loadModel(
    model: "lib\assets\image_classifier.tflite",
    labels: "lib\assets\image_labels.txt",
    );
  }
```

**File-Path:**

[image]

Resource I'm using:
https://pub.dev/packages/tflite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `/` in file path instead of `\`

```dart
loadModel() async{
  String res = await Tflite.loadModel(
  model: "lib/assets/image_classifier.tflite",
  labels: "lib/assets/image_labels.txt",
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, when I right click the file and click copy file path within flutter for some reason it gave me the wrong formatting which threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

It's not advicable to put your assets inside you lib directory. Always put at the same level with the lib directory